# Read session variable without invalidating context

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to read from a Session variable without re-rendering the template when it changes?

The scenario:

I change the style of elements dynamically using jQuery, but when a new element is created I want to set its default style (I know I could call the same jQuery command when the element is rendered)

**Example:**

```
<template name="image">
    <!-- How can I avoid -height- being reactive -->
    <img src="img.jpg" style="height: {{height}}">
</template>

Templates.image.height = function() {
    return Session.get("height");
};

Templates.controls.events = {
    'click #btn': function() {
        // Change the height of all exiting images
        $("img").css({height: Session.get("height")});
    }
};
```

I would like every new image added to have the height stored in the session variable without re-rendering the `img`. All the solutions I can think of feel like hacks.

Comment: I've edited my post, I'm not sure what you're doing with the button but to stop the image refreshing you can use isolate to change only s a small block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session stores its values in `Session.keys`, but they're serialized.  To deserialize them, you can use the `parse` function from https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/session/session.js :

```
var parse = function (serialized) {
  if (serialized === undefined || serialized === 'undefined')
    return undefined;
  return EJSON.parse(serialized);
};
```

Then, instead of `Session.get('key-name')`, do:
`parse(Session.keys['key-name'])`.  This should do the same as `Session.get` without invalidating any contexts.  Putting all this together, here's an approach that seems to work:

```
Session._parse = function (serialized) {
  if (serialized === undefined || serialized === 'undefined')
    return undefined;
  return EJSON.parse(serialized);
};

Session.getNonReactive = function (key) {
  var self = this;
  return self._parse(self.keys[key]);
};
```

**UPDATE 3/13/2013**:
Meteor just released v0.5.8, and with it a new function.  Here's the new way to do this:

```
Session.getNonReactive = function (key) {
  return Deps.nonreactive(function () { return Session.get(key); });
};
```

**UPDATE 15/2/2016**
Meter is currently deprecated, though it still works. Use `Tracker` instead:

```
Session.getNonReactive = function (key) {
  return Tracker.nonreactive(function () { return Session.get(key); });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use preserve : http://docs.meteor.com/#template_preserve

Why not use only jquery or handlebars to handle the value, why both? With consistency so you can manage you're code better.

I could help you with an example if you posted some code up

**Edit** That example with your code

Your code using handlebars only:

```
<template name="image">
    <!-- How can I avoid -height- being reactive -->
    {{#isolate}
    <img src="img.jpg" style="height:{{height}}">
    {{/isolate}}
</template>

Template.image.height = function() {
    return Session.get("height") || "0px"; //Default height is no session defined
};

Template.controls.events = {
    'click #btn': function() {
        //What does this do exactly?
        //$("img").css({height: Session.get("height")});

        Session.set("height","40px");
    }
};
```

To prevent your whole template being re-rendered put your reactive variable `{{height}}` in a `{{#isolate}}`. See reactivity isolation: http://docs.meteor.com/#isolate

Comment: Sounds great. But as soon as I add {{#isolate}} inside `style` it doesn't render as expected. Did you try it?

Comment: I tried it again without isolate and I can't get the images to refresh/redraw: gist with the project I used to test that @ https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5142555

Comment: So with this i've moved the isolate abit so this should work as you want

Comment: But now the image gets re-rendered every time the size changes. This is what I wanted to avoid in the first place. See original code.

Comment: Please try the code in the gist to see if it re renders, I can't get it to redraw, maybe you're doing something jqueryey to the image?