# Can I specify what session variables a Tracker.autorun() function depends on?

Tags: meteor, meteor-tracker

I currently have a piece of code similar to this:

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
    var foo = Session.get("foo")
    var bar = Session.get("bar")
    if (bar)
      console.log("foo changed and bar is set")
    else
      console.log("foo changed and bar is not set")
}
```

This code fails because the console prints one of the `foo changed` messages even when only `bar` changes.

I *have* to use both `foo` *and* `bar` inside my `Tracker.autorun()`, without it running whenever `bar` changes, and I want to do this by telling ´Tracker´ not to track `bar` or if possible by asking `Tracker` what set off the recompute, instead of separating the function into different autorunning functions or by manually keeping tabs on what `Session` variables have changed.

Comment: Your autorun should *not* run when an unrelated Session variable changes unless foo depends on it (in which case it's actually related).

Comment: You can simply set multiple Tracker.autorun for each function that depend on independent variables. 
In your example though, foo depends on bar as you pass it to the function.

Comment: Why do you say that? Multiple trackers can be a very powerful and efficient pattern.

Comment: ¬¬ found the answer two seconds after starting the bounty and saying I can't find the answer *anywhere on the internet*. Please don't hate me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it turns out, [this question has already been answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357868/read-session-variable-without-invalidating-context).

The answer is to use `Tracker.nonreactive()`. The fixed code from my question would be:

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
    var foo = Session.get("foo")

    var bar = Tracker.nonreactive(func() {
        return Session.get("bar")
    })

    if (bar)
      console.log("foo changed and bar is set")
    else
      console.log("foo changed and bar is not set")
}
```

Comment: `Deps` has been deprecated years ago for its new name, `Tracker`. Plus, you shouldn't post an answer if you found a duplicate but instead flag your post has a duplicate.

Comment: I updated the answer. However, I can't bring myself to close this question since, even though the answer is the same, the questions themselves aren't (and now mine's updated). I previously didn't find the answer because I was searching from the "excluding dependencies on Tracker" side and not from the "prevent Session from creating a dependency" side. I didn't even know I had to search for "invalidating context" to get an answer. So it's not a duplicate and there's merit to leaving it open. And I don't get why this answer is getting downvotes when it *works* and it *answers the question*.

Answer (score 2):

What about this approach?

```
var foo;
var bar;

Tracker.autorun(function() {
    foo = Session.get("foo")
    bar = Session.get("bar")
});

Tracker.autorun(function() {
    // Track for changes of `foo`
    Session.get("foo");

    if (bar)
        console.log("foo changed and bar is set")
    else
        console.log("foo changed and bar is not set")
});
```

**UPD.**
Oh, I see, you already have found a solution. Anyway, I will leave my answer here, maybe somebody will find it useful.

Comment: Hm. It does get around the autotracker. `Tracker.nonreactive()` is better but this should definitely work.

Answer (score -1):

You can split the autorun functions:

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
    var foo = Session.get("foo")
    // will run when foo changes
}


Tracker.autorun(function() {
    var bar = Session.get("bar")
    // will run when bar changes
}
```

Comment: @yudap, resticting the use of `foo` in your answer does not prevent the Autorun from running as you suggest: it only prevent the 'foo' code to run if foo is undefined, which if it is set at least once, means it will always run after, so your code really doesn't do much for performance!

Comment: what use is a Session variable if it is not set? The most common case is that it is set and it changes. Not that it is set or not set. if that's what you imply then say so in your explanation.

Comment: The thing is that I need to use the values of both `foo` and (in this example) also `bar`, but I don't want the function to run when `bar` changes. I guess I could add yet another variable to track whether it was `foo` the one that changed but I'd rather tell Tracker not to track `bar` in the first place